# How can i get count of customers per day by unique and repeat customer for specific date?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a result from my order table to get list of counts of customers who 1st time ordered and repeat orders. Something like below.

```
Date         1st time time   repeat order
2014-09-01      43               90
2014-09-02       3               45
2014-09-03      12               30
2014-09-04      32                0
2014-09-05       1               98
```

I am beginner in sql and i ma using mysql.

My table structure is like.

```
OrderNumber int
OrderDate datetime
CustomerID int
```

---

I have tried this query in mysql but it only gives me first timed ordered count.

```
SELECT DATE(OrderDate), COUNT(*) 
FROM orders T JOIN (
SELECT MIN(OrderDate) as minDate, CustomerID
FROM orders
GROUP BY CustomerID) T2 ON T.OrderDate = T2.minDate AnD T.CustomerID = T2.CustomerID
GROUP BY DATE(T.OrderDate)
```

Comment: what is the logic for `1st time` and `repeat` ?

Comment: Basically when customer1 place first time order on 2014-09-01. then for that date 1st time count will raise. and anfter that same customer will place order on 2014-09-02 then repeat order count will raise.

Comment: first-time and repeat order are based on customerid.

Comment: What if customer1 orders 2 times on 2014-09-01? How will the counts raise then?

Comment: yes then for 2014-09-01 date both counts will be 1.

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to generate a report where he can see based on a specific dates, how many new customer he has (1st order) and how many return customer he has. @MihirVadalia it is better to use datetime format rather than date format. This way, when customer1 orders twice on the same day you can distinguish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total orders per day by grouping on OrderDate:

```
SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(OrderNumber) AS total FROM orders GROUP BY OrderDate
```

And you can get the no. of first orders per day from the following query :

```
SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(q1.CustomerID) AS first FROM (SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate) AS OrderDate FROM orders GROUP BY CustomerID)q1 GROUP BY q1.OrderDate
```

Now join these two on OrderDate to get the distribution of first and repeated orders :

```
SELECT a.OrderDate, a.first, (b.total - a.first) AS repeated FROM
(SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(q1.CustomerID) AS first FROM (SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate) AS OrderDate FROM orders GROUP BY CustomerID)q1 GROUP BY q1.OrderDate)a
JOIN
(SELECT OrderDate, COUNT(OrderNumber) AS total FROM orders GROUP BY OrderDate)b
on(a.OrderDate = b.OrderDate)
```

Comment: What if for a specific day there were no orders from new customers? How would you NOT exclude that from the results?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly complicated query but this should do:

First Time Users: Just Group by customerID to get the min orderdate and then group by on that date to get the number of new users on a particular day. Query would look like this:

```
select date(mdate) as day, COUNT(*) from (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mDate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)q1 GROUP BY day;
```

Repeat Users: First filter out all such orderno which were placed as first orders and then do a group by orderdate to get repeat. Query would be :

```
select date(orderdate) day, COUNT(*) from (select * from orders where orderno not in (select orders.orderno  from orders JOIN (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mdate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)as order2 ON (orders.customerid = order2.customerid) and (orders.orderdate = order2.mdate))) as q1 GROUP BY day;
```

You can do a join on day for both these queries to get combined results in a way you mentioned. Let me know if doesn't work

EDIT:
This would be the complete query: Here I am doing a UNION on both left and right outer joins since it might happen that you come across where there are no new requests or no repeated requests. This would take care of both the scenarios.

```
select q2.*, q3.repeated from (select date(mdate) as day, COUNT(*) as first from (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mDate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)q1 GROUP BY day) as q2 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select date(orderdate) day, COUNT(*) as repeated from (select * from orders where orderno not in (select orders.orderno  from orders JOIN (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mdate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)as order2 ON (orders.customerid = order2.customerid) and (orders.orderdate = order2.mdate))) as q1 GROUP BY day) as q3 on q2.day = q3.day UNION select q2.*, q3.repeated from (select date(mdate) as day, COUNT(*) as first from (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mDate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)q1 GROUP BY day) as q2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN (select date(orderdate) day, COUNT(*) as repeated from (select * from orders where orderno not in (select orders.orderno  from orders JOIN (select customerid, min(orderdate) as mdate from orders GROUP BY CustomerID)as order2 ON (orders.customerid = order2.customerid) and (orders.orderdate = order2.mdate))) as q1 GROUP BY day) as q3 on q2.day = q3.day
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer but not sure is still can improve.

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(*) AS repeat_order_cnt FROM
(SELECT DATE(OrderDate) AS order_DT, userID, COUNT(*) AS no_of_order FROM order
AND YEAR(orderDate) = '2015'
AND MONTH(orderDate) = '01'
GROUP BY order_DT,userID) AS order2
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```