# MySQL Get cumulative customer transactions (not SQL transactions) on a monthly basis

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

:)

I have a simple table with transactions in it, nothing fancy, and I want to get for each month how many transactions are "first transactions". By first transaction we mean that the customer bought then for the first time.

The result I am trying to get is in the following form:

```
+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
|   Date  |  First Purchases In Month  |  Cumulative Sum  |
+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
| 01/2015 |           10               |       10         |
+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
| 02/2015 |           40               |       50         |
+---------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

The date format doesn't really matter, it could be a full date, I will parse it in Java later on anyway.

I found this post that does something similar although on a daily basis

[How can i get count of customers per day by unique and repeat customer for specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093264/how-can-i-get-count-of-customers-per-day-by-unique-and-repeat-customer-for-speci)

and I turned it into this:

```
set @csum := 0;
SELECT
    FirstOrderDate, MonthTotal, @csum:= @csum + MonthTotal AS AccumulatedTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT FirstOrderDate, SUM(month_total_new) as MonthTotal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            FirstOrderDate, COUNT(q1.consumerId) AS month_total_new
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                consumerId, MIN(date) AS FirstOrderDate
            FROM
                transaction
            GROUP BY
                consumerId
        ) AS q1
        GROUP BY
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM q1.FirstOrderDate),
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM q1.FirstOrderDate)
    ) AS s
    GROUP BY
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.FirstOrderDate),
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.FirstOrderDate)
) AS test;
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31538/7

The results seem to be correct, but using so many inner queries doesn't seem to be a best practice approach. What would be the proposed way to do such a thing?

Also, I would like to get 0 when a month has no "first transactions" in it rather than that date not appearing at all (like March in our fiddle where it has only one transaction which is not a "first transaction").

Thank you very much for any help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to summarize by customer to get the date of the first transaction per customer.  And then summarize that:

```
  select year(firstdate) as yyyy, month(firstdate) as mm,
         count(*) as NumFirsts
  from (select consumerid, min(date) as firstdate
        from transaction
        group by consumerid
       ) c
  group by year(firstdate), month(firstdate)
  order by year(firstdate), month(firstdate);
```

If you are reading this in java, you might just want to do the cumulative sum there.  Otherwise, you can do it in MySQL using variables:

```
select c.*, (@s := @s + NumFirsts) as CumeFirsts
from (select year(firstdate) as yyyy, month(firstdate) as mm,
             count(*) as NumFirsts
      from (select consumerid, min(date) as firstdate
            from transaction
            group by consumerid
           ) c
      group by year(firstdate), month(firstdate)
     ) c cross join
     (select @s := 0) params
order by yyyy, mm;
```

Handling months with zero first transactions is also a pain.  It helps if you have a calendar table or know that there are some transactions during the month.  For instance, you can do:

```
select ym.yyyy, ym.mm, coalesce(NumFirsts, 0) as NumFirsts,
       (@s := @s + coalesce(NumFirsts, 0)) as CumeFirsts
from (select distinct year(date) as yyyy, month(date)
      from transactions
     ) ym left join
     (select year(firstdate) as yyyy, month(firstdate) as mm,
             count(*) as NumFirsts
      from (select consumerid, min(date) as firstdate
            from transaction
            group by consumerid
           ) c
      group by year(firstdate), month(firstdate)
     ) c
     on c.yyyy = ym.yyyy and c.mm = y.mm cross join
     (select @s := 0) params
order by yyyy, mm;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help! :) I guess to keep the query more "readable" I will have to offload some work to Java as well! Cheers! :)